# React component not showing the correct data, but the component in the component does

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

## I'm making a preview modal for an ecommerce store.

## In the individual product page every props are correctly displayed, but the preview modal can't display some props for the products.

*I store the params for each product in a database, and fetch them to my storefront.*

Product page shows these: category, subcategory, name of the product, price (in HUF), brand, description.

[image: Product Page displays this]

**Product preview however CAN'T SHOW BRANDS.**
[image]

**So my info.tsx component looks like this:**

```
import { Product } from "@/types";
import Currency from "@/components/ui/currency";
import Button from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Heart } from "lucide-react";

interface InfoProps {
    data: Product;
}

const Info: React.FC<InfoProps> = ({
    data
}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2 className="text-gray-700">{data.category.name} \ <span className="text-green-500 font-bold">{data.subcategory.name}</span></h2>
            </div>
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-gray-900">{data.name}</h1>
            <div className="mt-3 flex items-end justify-between">
                <p className="text-2xl text-gray-900">
                    <Currency value={data.price} />
                </p>
            </div>
            <hr className="my-4" />
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-6">
                <div className="flex items-center gap-x-4">
                    <h3 className="text-gray-500">Contact us for further information.</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="inline items-center gap-x-4">
                    <h3 className="font-semibold text-zinc-900">Brand:</h3>
                    <div>
                        {data?.brand?.name}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="inline items-center gap-x-4">
                    <h3 className="font-semibold text-zinc-900">Description:</h3>
                    <div>
                        {data?.description}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-10 flex items-center gap-x-3">
                <Button className="flex items-center gap-x-2">
                    Favourites
                    <Heart />
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Info;
```

**My product page (which is showing everything correctly) looks like this:**

```
import getProducts from "@/actions/get-products";
import getProduct from "@/actions/get-product";
import Container from "@/components/ui/container";
import ProductList from "@/components/product-list";
import Gallery from "@/components/gallery";
import Info from "@/components/info";

export const revalidate = 0;

interface ProductPageProps {
    params: {
        productId: string;
    }
}

const ProductPage: React.FC<ProductPageProps> = async ({
    params
}) => {
    const product = await getProduct(params.productId);
    const suggestedProducts = await getProducts({
        categoryId: product?.category?.id
    })
    const filteredSuggestedProducts = suggestedProducts.filter(suggestedProduct => suggestedProduct.id !== product.id);

    return (
        <div className="bg-white">
            <Container>
                <div className="px-4 py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <div className="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-2 lg:items-start lg:gap-x-8">
                        <Gallery images={product.images} />
                        <div className="mt-10 px-4 sm:mt-16 sm:px-0 lg:mt-0">
                            <Info data={product} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr className="my-10" />
                    <ProductList title={"Kapcsolódó termékeink:"} items={filteredSuggestedProducts} />
                </div>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductPage;
```

**My preview-modal WHICH IS NOT SHOWING BRANDS looks like this:**

```
"use client";

import usePreviewModal from "@/hooks/use-preview-modal";
import Modal from "@/components/ui/modal";
import Gallery from "@/components/gallery";
import Info from "@/components/info";

const PreviewModal = () => {
    const previewModal = usePreviewModal();
    const product = usePreviewModal((state) => state.data);

    if (!product) {
        return null;
    }

    console.log('Product in PreviewModal:', product);

    return (
        <Modal open={previewModal.isOpen} onClose={previewModal.onClose}>
            <div className="grid w-full grid-cols-1 items-start gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-12 lg:gap-x-8">
                <div className="sm:col-span-4 lg:col-span-5">
                    <Gallery images={product.images} />
                </div>
                <div className="sm:col-span-8 lg:col-span-7">
                    <Info data={product} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}

export default PreviewModal;
```

**My use-preview-modal.ts hooks look like this:**

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import { Product } from "@/types";

interface PreviewModalStore {
    isOpen: boolean;
    data?: Product;
    onOpen: (data: Product) => void;
    onClose: () => void;
};

const usePreviewModal = create<PreviewModalStore>((set) => ({
    isOpen: false,
    data: undefined,
    onOpen: (data: Product) => set({ data, isOpen: true }),
    onClose: () => set({ isOpen: false })
}));

export default usePreviewModal;
```

I tried console logging what data is being passed to the preview-modal, but

```
Object { id: "e0773866-a4ae-466c-8a28-82ffb1d2082c", storeId: "e8cc7cb1-8fb3-46d2-8230-1514f2a88cec", categoryId: "1c674538-810a-4a2e-aa30-76d795de1e6d", name: "Deerhunter Chasse polár kabát", price: "23900", isFeatured: true, isArchived: false, brandId: "958f1eee-5695-456a-935f-c4ab9f5039ab", description: "Nagyon jó kis kabi.", createdAt: "2023-11-09T09:33:27.948Z", … }
```

As you can see, this object does not have the Brand attributes avaible. **But why tho?**

Comment: maybe data that is coming to preview component has another type not product? Because it has brandId maybe you should fetch it from DB by this uuid to get brand object?